# Unable to obtain configuration from Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

Following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-single-page-app-webapi?tabs=app-reg-preview) by Microsoft, the JavaScript application is not able to access the API protected by Azure AD B2C. The application is able to login/authenticate, but when clicking the `Call Web API` button, the following message is output onto the page:

> Web APi returned:
>   "AuthenticationFailed: IDX10803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://b2c-tenant-name.microsoftonline.com/tfp/b2c-tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_signupsignin/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'."

How can this be repaired? What change is required to allow the JavaScript SPA to call the protected web API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well that URL looks a bit odd.
It should be something like:

```
https://b2c-tenant-name.b2clogin.com/b2c-tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=B2C_1_signupsignin
```

I got this from the Run user flow feature in the Azure portal.

You can't use microsoftonline.com URLs any more.
They were deprecated.
The host is now b2clogin.com.